# Wet fillings in chocolate

Tags: chocolate

Water is the arch-nemesis of chocolate. So how do you put water-based fillings into chocolates without splitting the chocolate? I've tried this a few times, and it never seems to work properly.

(Most particularly, I'm trying to do a fondant filling. But since fondant is just sugar with water in it... that's not going to work very well.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To correct your statement:
Water is the arch enemy of *liquid* chocolate...

You can even let melted chocolate and liquid touch, this will not cause the chocolate to seize, stirring might.

If you want to create a filled bite of chocolate-encased deliciousness often called Belgian [praline](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Praline) (but names may vary), you can go different routes:

- Prepare a (semi-)solid centre, e.g. a piece of [marzipan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marzipan) or, if firm enugh to cut, your fondant, then coat it by dipping it in tempered chocolate.
- Prepare a hollow shell by pouring tempered chocolate into molds and pouring it out again before it sets. Then fill the shell with your desired filling, leaving a bit of space to the top. Close the shell by piping or pouring more chocolate on it. Let cool between steps and before unmolding.
- For really liquid fillings like liqueur, you need shells that have only a small opening. You can make them yourself, either by using a special mold with a small opening or by making semi-spheres, "glueing" two halves together and then using a warm tool to melt a hole into the ball. Or you can order them from specialized suppliers. Fill the shell with your liquid filling, then close the hole by piping a drop of chocolate on it.
  Optional: dip the filled object in chocolate to hide seams etc.

Comment: ...so the key is to let the chocolate *set* before putting wet stuff on it?

Comment: @MathematicalOrchid Yes!